# Matter.js: finding if a certain object is touching at least one body

Tags: matter.js

I want a way to see if my player (which is a box) is colliding with another body from the world, any other body than my player.

I didn't find a way to do it in the documentation, only in pair or in a list. But if I put the entire world in the list, it's going to count other collisions without the player.

Comment: Can you show the method you've tried? I assume `Matter.Query.collides()`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Matter.Query.collides(boxBody, arrayOfAllOtherEntitiesExceptBoxBody)`](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Query.html#method_collides). By excluding the player box from the second parameter collision array, there won't be a false positive self-collision on the player box.

`Query.collides()` returns an array of collisions, so it may be a bit expensive if you just need a boolean (I'm not sure how it's actually implemented, just a guess. It's good not to prematurely optimize). `Matter.Events.on(engine, "collisionStart", cb)` can be used as an alternative. In the callback, iterate the colliding body pairs to see if any are the player.

If use `Query.collides()`, you'll likely run it on `collisionStart` and `collisionEnd` rather than `beforeUpdate` to avoid running it more than necessary.

Here's a minimal example illustrating both techniques. Use the mouse to move the player.

```js
const engine = Matter.Engine.create();
engine.gravity.y = 0; // enable top-down
const map = {width: 300, height: 300};
const render = Matter.Render.create({
  element: document.body,
  engine,
  options: {...map, wireframes: false},
});
const player = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(
  map.width / 2, map.height / 2, 25, 25, {
    render: {fillStyle: "green"},
  },
);
const rnd = (lo, hi) => Math.random() * (hi - lo) + lo;
const enemies = [...Array(25)].map(() =>
  Matter.Bodies.circle(
    rnd(0, map.width),
    rnd(0, map.height),
    rnd(5, 15),
    {
      isSensor: true,
      render: {fillStyle: "yellow"}
    }
  )
);
Matter.Composite.add(engine.world, [...enemies, player]);
Matter.Events.on(engine, "collisionEnd", event => {
  const collisions = Matter.Query.collides(player, enemies);

  if (collisions.length === 0) {
    player.render.fillStyle = "green";
  }
});
Matter.Events.on(engine, "collisionStart", event => {
  for (const {bodyA, bodyB} of event.pairs) {
    if (bodyA === player || bodyB === player) {
      player.render.fillStyle = "red";
    }
  }
});
document
  .querySelector("canvas")
  .addEventListener("mousemove", ({offsetX: x, offsetY: y}) => {
    Matter.Body.setPosition(player, {x, y});
  });
Matter.Render.run(render);
Matter.Runner.run(Matter.Runner.create(), engine);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.19.0/matter.min.js"></script>
```

Yet another option is to tap into the `collisionActive` event. Here's an example that would work in the above code:

```js
Matter.Events.on(engine, "collisionActive", event => {
  const collisionWithPlayer = event.pairs.find(e =>
    e.bodyA === player || e.bodyB === player
  );
  console.log(!!collisionWithPlayer);
});
```

`.some()` can be used instead of `.find()` if you only care about getting the boolean. Or if you want an array of all collisions between the player and other bodies:

```js
Matter.Events.on(engine, "collisionActive", event => {
  const collisionsWithPlayer = event.pairs.filter(e =>
    e.bodyA === player || e.bodyB === player
  );
  console.log(collisionsWithPlayer.length);
});
```